# Automatic transfer large files between 2 sites behind fire walls

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive

I thought this will have an answer on this site, but after some searching I couldn't find anything useful.

Here is my situation.  I want to setup an automatic way to transfer some backup from one computer on one site to another computer on another site.  Both sites are heavily firewalled, but http and email are opened, also GoToMyPC, dropbox, and google drive works on both pc's.  There is only 1 file to be transferred, but it is about 5-10GB in size.  We tried some combination of scripting and dropbox, but dropbox transfer is just too slow.  We use google drive manually now, and we don't know how to automate that...

Is there any way we can do this?  (fast and work through http).  It is difficult to convenience management to allow for any open port on the firewall.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If both side are linux / Mac, you can use Rsync and that can be automated. Do you have VPN access between the 2 sites?

Comment: Agree with you but unfortunately both are Windows and no VPN connectivity

Comment: BitTorrent Sync is a possibility. It does automatic sync when there are changes, but it may be firewalled. If HTTP is opened, you can have the file available publicly on the web with a link that only you know, and have the other side run a Task Scheduler with wget with that specific file link and it will download at scheduled times. It is somewhat insecure but if that link is never referenced anywhere on the web, it is not searchable. And you can also prevent Directory Listing on that particular page to secure it.

Answer (score 0):

Bigger file transfer would mean more chances of corruption, for regular works better use a personal bit torrent network.